# find href link from webpage using java

Tags: java, html

I am reading a URL and get the response of that page using URLConnection in java.

I am getting all the html content as response. But when I am looking into the href link of anchor tag, it shows only

```
<a href = zzz.html />
```

But in browser page, the respective anchor tag's original url is goes to

```
<a href = host/zzz.html />
```

To get this original url, I tried as follows,

```
1. Converting response into string
2. Read each line and check whether that string contains "href="
3. If exists, then I just replace it with "href=url.getHost()"
```

By this way, I am able to get the URL (--host/zzz.html).

In some websites, pages placed in some other folder and accessing link from other folders.

for example,

I am looking in (--zzz.com/123/abc/aa.html). This page has a link as

```
<a href = "me.html" />
```

If I click this link, it goes to (--zzz.com/123/abc/me.html) in browser. In this case I am able to take host as zzz.com only.

If I substitute href link as I mentioned above in 3 steps, the link changes as (--zzz.com/me.html)..

How do I get that link as (--zzz.com/123/abc/me.html)  from java code.

hope someone can help.

Here is my code to get a href urls.

```
    public static void main(String[] argh) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        URL url = new URL("http://www.nakkheeran.in/Users/frmMagazine.aspx?M=2");
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("root:pass".getBytes());
        String encoding = new String(encodedBytes);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        connection.connect();

        InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        try {
            fWriter = new FileWriter(new File("f:\\fileName.html"));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String s = line.toString();
                if (s.contains("<a ")) {
                    if (s.contains("href=\"http")) {
                        writer.write(line);
                    } else if (s.contains("href=\"//")) {
                        s = s.replace("href=\"//", "href=\"http://");
                        writer.write(s);
                    }else if (s.contains("href=\"/")) {
                        s = s.replace("href=\"/",   "href=\"http://" + url.getHost() + "/");
                        writer.write(s);
                    } else {
                        writer.write(s);
                    }
                } 
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try using jsoup Go to http://jsoup.org/.
Follow the instructions.

(download the jar files and add to your classpath).

Here you can check this program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLUtils {
 private HTMLUtils() {}

public static List<String>extractLinks(String url) throws IOException {
final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();// enter the url

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

// href ...To get all the href on that website
for (Element link : links) {
  result.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
}

// img ...to get the images from website
for (Element src : media) { 
  result.add(src.attr("abs:src"));
}

// js, css, ...
for (Element link : imports) {
  result.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
}
return result;
}


public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
String site = "url";//enter the url
List<String> links = HTMLUtils.extractLinks(site);
for (String link : links) {
  System.out.println(link);
}
 }
}
```

you can get all the href from this program..

Comment: Thanks. This shows fine. But how do I replace them in my respective respone. Is it possible? Ans Also is there no way to do this in core java?

Comment: Yes you can do it using url connector.    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html     check this link.

Comment: Yes, This is how I am reading response now, I have confusion on how we can change the URL while iterating for loop of jsoup elements. I updated my question with the code. Pls take a look.

Comment: For example, I have 3 anchor tags in that url, how to change the links of them using Jsoup. Please assist as I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it like this

```
  String str = "<a href = "zzz.com/123/abc/me.html" />";    
  String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("<a href =") + 1, str.indexOf("/>"));
```

here you will get  `zzz.com/123/abc/me.html` in result
so replace it in your html.

```
your_html_string.replace(result, "url.getHost()");
```